# Windows Crashing after Fresh Install

Tags: windows, crash

I have windows 8, I just tried a fresh install, and after about 5 minutes of use sometimes the computer will "crash." All applications will eventually just lockup and not respond, and eventually it will go to the windows 8 error screen with a message of Critical Process Died.

I have memtested and it found no errors.

What else could be the problem?

I am thinking it could be a bad SSD, is there a way to test this?

Thanks

Comment: How long did you run memtest? Have you changed any hardware recently? Also, please upload your minidump file.

Comment: @ekaj For almost 2 hours, It's still running with 0 errors. And nothing is being dumped, in event viewer it says crash initialization failed. And no the problem is, it's been doing this for almost a year, but the computer wouldn't crash for weeks. Now it's basically unusuable.